# Moving object while following it with camera

Tags: objects, 3d-view, camera, shortcut

I'm looking for a shortcut to lock camera (3D view, not the object: "Camera") temporarily onto an object while moving it (object). For example if I move a cube in x-axis and it leaves the visible area in viewport, I could press a shortcut to follow the object without the need the disencage from the action of moving the cube (and scrolling back etc..). This is a feature I found really helpful in Unreal Engine 4 and I've been trying to find a way to do it in Blender, without success. 
Also, I know this is pretty lazy, but aren't that what shortcuts are made for :)
Thanks!

Comment: Recentering on the object is done with Numpad period without any locking. You can use Lock to Object feature on the Properties shelf > View rollout, but that will affect viewport much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a camera object and locking the camera object to the view in the side panel settings when selecting a camera object (under view).

When you go into camera view (numberpad 0) it will move with the 3d camera.

Edit* You can setup multiple cameras this way and scroll through them by setting markers in the time line.

Comment: I guess that works, thank you for taking the time to reply. I'm suprised that Blender doesn't have a shortcut for such useful feature!